# Serial No for FTL in table

Tags: html, freemarker

How to display the list index in `freemarker` for serial Number, I have a list debitnotedetails and how to show the serial number in the td. Is there any method in freemarker

```
<#list debitNoteDetails as debitNote>
    <#if debitNote_index % 2 == 0>
        <tr style="font-size:12px;">
    <#else>
        <tr style="font-size:12px;height:10px;background-color: #ececec;">
    </#if>
            <td style="width:100px;height:20px;" cellpadding="5">${debitNoteDetails.index}</td>
        </tr>
</#list>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by serial number? You are already using `debitNote_index` there, which is the the 0-based index of the item. Anyway, here's the concise way of doing it (with 1 based counting):

```
<#list debitNoteDetails as debitNote>
    <tr style="font-size:12px<#if debitNote?is_even_item>;height:10px;background-color: #ececec;</#if>">
        <td style="width:100px;height:20px;" cellpadding="5">${debitNote?counter}</td>
    </tr>
</#list>
```

Note that the above requires FreeMarker 2.3.23. In earlier version you could use `debitNote_index`.